# Process order with saved CC

Tags: payment-methods

I accidentally left activated the Saved CC payment method, I usually use it to test the checkout prcocess, and there are several orders that were made using this payment method.
Is there any way to automatically process these orders through the default payment method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your admin, inside the order details you will find the cc info, but try to avoid this method because is really insecure...

Comment: Less the CVV which, in case you need it, you will need to contact the customer. No automatic processing on this method, Saved CC was only ever intended for manual credit card processing, and breaks PCI-DSS as generically implemented by most shop owners.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to run manually through your merchant

Comment: How can I retrieve the payment information in order to process them manually?